# Why does changing extracellular concentration of a highly-permeable solute affect membrane potential (e.g. hyperkalemia)

Tags: electrochemistry, biochemistry

Okay, this is an embarrassing question to ask and expose just how little I understand membrane potential given my field, but I've been trying to understand on my own for 3 years at this point and it's clearly going nowhere.

So, when you're first introduced to membrane potential, it's essentially explained as "with more positive charges inside the cell relative to outside, membrane potential increases". This causes confusion once the Nernst equation is introduced and it seems to be opposite, but the way I've explained it to myself is "the resting membrane potential for a given extracellular and intracellular concentration of an ion is the membrane potential *needed* to hold it in equilibrium at those concentrations, which is established by that ion plus all other ions' net charges. Not the membrane potential *due to* that ion's concentrations" i.e. to hold a positive ion mostly intracellular, you need a negative intracellular-extracellular electrical difference, so you say the resting membrane potential for those concentrations is negative.

Where I lose my absolute marbles is trying to understand how in vivo changing the concentration of a highly-permeable ion changes the equilibrium potential difference. Take hyperkalemia. Yeah, to hold the concentration gradient of potassium at less of a gradient (same intracellular concentration as normal, higher extracellular concentration), you would not need as negative of a potential difference. But I can't understand how the *actual* potential difference changes in that situation. Assuming there's no permeability to other ions (obviously incorrect, but their permeability is much lower than potassium, so I feel making that assumption should at least lead you in the right direction despite not giving you the exact correct calculation for potential difference, right?), the distribution of electrical charges has no reason to change to maintain this new concentration gradient. Instead, the highly-permeable ion should flow along its electrochemical gradient to reach its equilibrium concentrations. Why isn't this what happens?